# WordPress - запись не видит тему

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть своя верстка, которую интегрировал в тему WordPress. При создании новой страницы через админку, страница создается без проблем с дизайном верстки.
А вот когда создаю новую запись, она будто не видит верстку и просто показывает обычную запись, белый экран с черным текстом контента записи.

Верстка находится в файле page.php , может, я где-то сделал не так? Только недавно начал изучать wordpress.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Исследуй сайт на наличие ошибок,они отображаться в консоли браузера, F12 . Если там будут отображаться ошибки, виде красный кружков с крестиков, их нужно будет исправить и все будет ок. Чаще всего из-за неправильно подключенных библиотек

Comment: single.php отвечает за отображения записей. page.php - этот файл отображает страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> может я где то сделал не так ?

Во-первых как сказали выше `page.php` это для страницы. Для записи нужен `single.php`.  См [Иерархия шаблонов](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Во вторых судя по скрину потреяно подключение хедера ([wp-head()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head)) (наверняка и [wp-footer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer))

И в-третьих, внесение изменений в тему нужно осуществлять в помощью [механизма дочерних тем](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон page.php отвечает за вывод страницы, а за вывод записи - single.php. Надо верстку делать и там. Почитайте про [иерархию шаблонов WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Answer (score 0):

`page.php` это - шаблон отдельной страницы, используется для отображения запрошенной страницы Page.

Вам необходимо создать файл `single.php` и поместить туда код page.php. 
Собственно `single.php` - Шаблон страницы одиночного поста. Используется, когда запрошен конкретный пост. Для этого и других шаблонов по запросу используется `index.php`, если в вашей теме нет соответствующего файла шаблона.